# Website doesn't provide cookie (csrf token) when connecting over proxy. Why/how?

Tags: http, cookies, proxy, csrf, python

The Python code below should grab a [CSRF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens) cookie from Instagram.com, but I get an error message when running the program through any sort of HTTPS or SOCKS5 proxy, informing me that the CSRF cookie isn't provided.

If `s.proxies` is commented out so that the program isn't being run via a proxy, it works just fine without error, and Instagram.com provides a CSRF token cookie.

So my question is: how does Instagram detect that I'm running the program from a proxy?  In other words, how does it differentiate between a normal request and a request running through a proxy?

```
import requesocks
import requests

s = requesocks.session()
# Tor uses the 9050 port as the default socks port
s.proxies = {'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/'
s.get(url)
tok = s.cookies['csrftoken']

#Outputs: 
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#File "tor.py", line 24, in <module>
#tok = s.cookies['csrftoken']
#KeyError: 'csrftoken
```

Comment: are you sure its instagram that is filtering out the csrf token? I would not be so quick to assume the proxy is blameless in this.

Comment: "..through any sort of https or socks5 proxy.." - really any sort? Or just any kind of proxy which uses Tor or other common privacy enhancing technologies as the endpoint? Did you try with a local proxy installation which uses your original IP address as source of the requests?

Comment: Could you add a line to `print s.cookies`? Perhaps 'csrftoken' is `CSRFToken` so it's the capitalization that's fooling you..

Comment: Proxies might add HTTP headers like `X-Forwarded-For`. Detecting these headers server-side can be enough to consider you're behind a proxy. But I'm not sure that the "how does instagram detect I'm behind a proxy" is relevant in your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple =) In no-proxy case you're tracing all the redirects *yourself*, so it's no problem to handle it. A *proxy* can be tricky as the *proxy itself*(not Tor case, but there are programs that behave a bit weird), so the *proxy component* for your language can be. Especially it happens frequently with HTTP and HTTPS proxies. Use a `tcpdump` - it will show you the problem. If you will see no csrf token in your proxy-to-your-code dump, then take a look, maybe it's a captcha page or something. If you actually see a csrf token in a dump, but not in your code - the proxy component is a problem for sure